# is there any way When visitors try to add the products into shopping cart, they will be asked to login.?

Tags: cart

When visitors try to add the products into shopping cart, they will be asked to login first. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension available to help you achieve this functionality.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-only-add-to-cart.html

Comment: on install now button the below key shows let me how can i use that?
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Codewix_LoginonlyAtc-0.1.0

Comment: If you want to download and install the extension not using Magento connect you can download the extension files using this site - http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed possible.

As far as i know, you have 2 options here, you can either:

1. Look into creating a custom module that observes the event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add`. With this you can then check if a customer is logged in and execute some functionallity which displays a pop-up/redirects the user etc...
2. Another option is to look at the template file `app/design/frontend/[template]/[package]/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml` and wrap the 'add to cart' button in an if statement to display an alert for the customer to log in before adding to cart.

Answer (score 1):

you can create an observer on the event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` that looks like this

```
public function checkLogin($observer)
{
    if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
         Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addWarning(Mage::helper('customer')->__('you must be logged in to add products to cart'))
         Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl("customer/account/login"))->sendResponse();
         exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: and this event need to check on onclick the "Add to cart "button ?

Comment: Marius: can you please give me location where i can create this observer and how can i call this

Comment: @Simmi: https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Using+the+Event-Observer+Method+in+Magento+1.x

Answer (score 0):

Step1 : Please rewrite Mage_Checkout_CartController with your custom module controller.

Step2 : override addAction() function from your custom module controller.

Step3: Add following code into addAction() function

```
if (! $cart->getCustomerSession()->getCustomer()->getId() && $cart->getQuote()->getCustomerId()) {
  $this->_redirect('customer/account/login');
}
```

Just after

```
$cart = $this->_getCart();
```

Comment: This is not working

Comment: $customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
            if (!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {            
              $this->_redirect('customer/account/login');
              return $this;
            }

Comment: i add above code on checkout index action but i want page not redirected simply show the warning for login